# Logitech M590 bluetooth pairing

Tags: debian, mouse, bluetooth

My logitech M590 mouse isn't recognized by `blueman`. My current distro is Debian 9.9. The mouse worked fine in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this might work might not. While the computer is running unplug the mouse wait a couple seconds or longer than try plugging it back in. Maybe it will pair? 
The driver should be generic. Or your mouse is not recognized and that is not believable.

Answer (score 0):

Your device looks like it came with a Logitech Unifying receiver.

There is software written especially for Logitech Unifying receivers. It's called solaar.

It has helped me with Logitech wireless mice several times.

Solaar by itself is command line only but depending on your desktop environment, there may be integrations/plugins/etc. that give you a GUI in your notifications or similar.